# PHP/JQuery/AJAX - Log-in form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have problems creating the log-in part of my website. Here is my js file general.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button#submit").click(function (){
               $("div#ack").html("please enter username and password");

    alert("hi");
    if($("#username").val()==""||$("#password").val()=="")
        $("div#ack").html("please enter username and password");
    else
        $.post( $("#login").attr("action"), 
                $("#login :input").serializeArray(),
                function(data){
                    $("div#ack").html(data);
                });
    $("#login").submit( function(){
        return false;
    });
 });
 });
```

Here is the PHP file : auth.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');

// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysqli_error());
}

// Grab User submitted information
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["password"])); 

// Select the database to use
mysqli_select_db("NDE",$con);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT username, password FROM fanusers WHERE username =       $username");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row["username"]==$username && $row["password"]==$password)
echo"You are a validated user.";
else
echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";

?>
```

And the index.html :

```
<form id="login"  action="auth.php" method="POST" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    <button id="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
```

I don't understand why it directly goes to the PHP page and not passing through the AJAX... If someone can help me a bit it would be great

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forget to load jquery there. Load it and check it must work ,Added fiddle demo Check in Firebug Network XHR window you will get Ajax response.

[`FIDDLE DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/2tpC2)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("button#submit").click(function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
           $("div#ack").html("please enter username and password");
...}
```